# Typescript if \n exist in a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am iterating over each character of a string and trying to identify each new line character found.

Doing like that :

```
csv_data: string; //It is of format .csv -> "toto;tata;titi\nhey;hello;hi" for example
for(var i=0; i<csv_data.length; i++) {

    if(csv_data[i] == '\\') //Assuming I will only have \ character for \n
        console.log("New line found! backslash");

    //I tried also that
    if(csv_data[i] == '\n')
        console.log("New line found! backslash plus n");
}
```

I know that I have `\n` in my string, because after doing `csv_data.split('\n')` it returns me all my lines in an array.

When I try to print character by character it prints a blank character where it should be a `\n`

Any ideas ?

**EDIT** : it was a cache issue `if(csv_data[i] == '\n')` worked.

Comment: if you split by '\n' then in your output array there are not exist '\n'. it is removed when split

Comment: check this out `"\u000A" === "\n"` `\n` is just a representation for the newline character in a string. It's not literally a `backslash` followed by a `n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are mixing '\n' which is a single newline character and '\\n' which is a backslash character followed by a `n`.

If you really have newlines in you CSV file, then the first test (`== '\\'`) will never find them, because there are no backslash in your file.

If you have newline representations, using a backslash followed by a `n`, then the second test (`== '\n'`) will never find them, because it is searching for real newline characters.

Comment: `if(csv_data[i] == '\n')` it worked. I had a cache issue so my test result was based on a older version.